# is there a return-first-Some analogue to the try operator?

Tags: rust

I have some code that looks like this

```
    if let Some(x) = { foo() } {
        return Some(x);
    } else if let Some(x) = { bar() } {
        return Some(x);
    }
    None
```

is there any way to express this as something like

```
return_first_some_or_none!(
  foo(),
  bar(),
)
```

? I'd still want the lazy evaluation (i.e. bar() is not evaluated if foo() is Some)

Answer (score 6):

Yes, the [`Option::or_else()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/option/enum.Option.html#method.or_else) utility method does exactly what you are looking for:

```
fn foo() -> Option<i32> { todo!() }
fn bar() -> Option<i32> { todo!() }

fn example() -> Option<i32> {
    foo().or_else(bar)
}
```

You can chain `.or_else` multiple times in this way, and you can pass a closure instead of a function if you want the logic inline.